# RxJS 5 - function called twice

Tags: rxjs5, redux-observable

I'm trying to show a confirmation Modal, before deleting a line using RxJS.

- The code below works fine if I delete 1 line.
- When I delete a second line, then `deleteLineFulfilled` is called 2 times.
- If I delete a third line, then `deleteLineFulfilled` is called 3 times and so on...

Any idea why?

```
const deleteLineEpic = (action$, store) =>
action$.ofType(DELETE_LINE_REQUEST)
    .flatMap((action) => Observable.merge(
                Observable.of(showModalYesNo('CONFIRM_DELETE')),
                action$.ofType(MODAL_YES_CLICKED).map(() =>
                    deleteLineFulfilled(action.line)
                )
                .takeUntil(action$.ofType(MODAL_NO_CLICKED))
           ));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`action$` is a perpetual observable, and it will only stop when an action of the type `MODAL_NO_CLICKED` is dispatched - from your code it's hard to say when that happens, you should add an `.take(1)` before the `.takeUntil(...)`.

---

However with this architecture you have to make sure that there *has* to be either an `MODAL_YES_CLICKED` or `MODAL_NO_CLICKED` emitted and that the emission cannot be skipped.

A simpler way would be to implement the confirm-dialog, subscribe to the result and then only dispatch the delete-action if the result was `YES` and if the result was `NO` don't even dispatch the action. That way you'll have a much cleaner action-epic.

Comment: The only issue is that I have some validation to run before showing the confirmation Modal (didn't include them in the code), and the validation is happening when the `DELETE_LINE_REQUEST` is called. But I get your point. Thanks for your help.

Comment: In your explanation, you said "from your code it's hard to say when that happens", Let's say I want to do it on `MODAL_NO_CLICK` or `MODAL_YES_CLICK`. Adding `takeUntil(MODAL_YES_CLICK)` stops the observable before even dispatching `deleteLineFulfilled`. Is it possible to do it that way?

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
        .first() // $action is a perpetual observable. Only take the first one.
        .takeUntil(action$.ofType(MODAL_NO_CLICKED))
```